# Applying a for-loop within purrr::pmap()

Tags: r, for-loop, purrr

From two columns `soldier` and `superior` I am trying to create a list column of the superior ranks above each `soldier` that I can later unnest to form long data will all ranks above each soldier's rank. So for "Srg" the values would be "Lt, Maj, Col, Gen", and for "Maj" the value would be "Col, Gen".

Currently the only way I've found to apply this for-loop to the entire dataframe using `purrr::pmap()` requires me to hardcode in variable and dataframe names into the for-loop.

Is there a way I could extract these ranks in a more generalizable function that took data and variable names as arguments?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# Create test data
data <-
  dplyr::tibble(
    soldier = c("Srg", "Lt", "Maj", "Col", "Gen"),
    superior  = c("Lt", "Maj", "Col", "Gen", NA)
  )

# Define custom function
get_ranks_above <- function(id, max_steps = 5){

  ranks_above <- vector("list", length = max_steps)

  for (i in 1:max_steps) {
    ranks_above[[i]] <- 
      data.frame(
        superior_list = data$superior[data$soldier == id]
      )

    id <- ranks_above[[i]]$superior_list
  }

  do.call(rbind, ranks_above)
}

# Apply custom function
data_ranked <- 
  data %>%
  mutate(
    ranks_above = pmap(
      list(id = soldier), 
      get_ranks_above
    )
  )

# Unnest list column and add numeric ranks
data_ranked %>% 
  unnest(ranks_above) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  group_by(soldier) %>% 
  mutate(rank_from_top = seq(n(),1)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

When I try to write the custom function `get_ranks_above()` with arguments for data and variable names I get an error message: 
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Element 1 has length 2, not 1 or 5..

```
get_ranks_above <- function(data, id = soldier, lower_rank = data$soldier, upper_rank = data$superior, max_steps = 5){

  ranks_above <- vector("list", length = max_steps)

  for (i in 1:max_steps) {
    ranks_above[[i]] <- 
      data.frame(
        superior_list = upper_rank[lower_rank == id]
      )

    id <- ranks_above[[i]]$superior_list
  }

  do.call(rbind, ranks_above)
}

data_ranked <- 
  data %>%
  mutate(
    ranks_above = pmap(
      list(
        data = data, 
        id = soldier, 
        lower_rank = data$soldier, 
        upper_rank = data$superior, 
        max_steps = 5
      ), 
      get_ranks_above
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do what you are trying to do is to use an ordered factor to compare ranks with each other. Here I can use `parse_factor` to create the ordered factor, using `ranks` as the levels and specifying that the levels should be ordered as given (note that `ranks` is already in order). That makes the `superior` easy to determine, we just go through the `ranks` and check which ones are `>` than our current `soldier`, and subset `ranks` accordingly. Then we can `unnest` as desired and have a our long form data.

```r
library(tidyverse)
ranks <- c("Srg", "Lt", "Maj", "Col", "Gen")
set.seed(12345)
some_soldiers <- tibble(
  soldier = sample(ranks, 5)
)
some_soldiers
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   soldier
#>   <chr>  
#> 1 Col    
#> 2 Gen    
#> 3 Maj    
#> 4 Lt     
#> 5 Srg

some_soldiers %>%
  mutate(
    soldier = parse_factor(soldier, levels = ranks, ordered = TRUE),
    superior = map(soldier, ~ ranks[which(ranks > .x)])
  ) %>%
  unnest()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    soldier superior
#>    <ord>   <chr>   
#>  1 Col     Gen     
#>  2 Maj     Col     
#>  3 Maj     Gen     
#>  4 Lt      Maj     
#>  5 Lt      Col     
#>  6 Lt      Gen     
#>  7 Srg     Lt      
#>  8 Srg     Maj     
#>  9 Srg     Col     
#> 10 Srg     Gen
```

Created on 2018-08-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Haha, almost identical solution ^^ btw, you don't need the `which`.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this problem with ordered factors. Once you have a table with all the information, you can easily merge it to any data frame. General idea:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
sld_levels <- c("Srg", "Lt", "Maj", "Col", "Gen")
tibble(sld_rank = factor(sld_levels, 
                         levels = sld_levels, 
                         ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(rank_above = map(.x = sld_rank, ~sld_rank[.x < sld_rank]))
```

Comment: The data are actually much more complex than this reprex. The task is closer to saving the unique id numbers of every manager above each employee.

Comment: Well then, I guess you need to be more specific in your example. Given that it might be further away from the logic of the original question, you should probably explain it in a new question.

Comment: I have tried to simplify and clarify the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976112/generalize-a-for-loop-for-use-in-a-custom-function